Please help me identify this battery connector
I wasn't particularly successful with a parametric search on digikey and couldn't find it on https://connectorbook.com either. Pitch is about 1.25mm (-ish). It's used to connect a single cell LiPo to a PCB.
The SMT jack looks a bit like a Molex Pico EZmate but the plugs don't match. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.




On which device that is? Is it Molex Pico-EZmate?

Proprietary PCB, European (possibly German) design.

The plug looks like a Hirose DF57H-3S-1.2C(08). The mating header would be DF57H-3P-1.2V(21).

Yes! I was going though the usual suspects, Molex, Amphenol, TE. Didn't look at Hirose for some reason. Thank you so much!
